# Python difference between partially known dates

Tags: python, regex, date, datetime, substring

I am trying to calculate the difference between the current date and a given (partially known) date. For example: Valid date formats (YYYY-MM-DD) are listed below.

```
YYYY-MM-DD
YYYY-MM-??
YYYY-??-??
????-??-??
```

Examples, for the current day (2021-07-04), the results would then be

```
2021-12-02 -> 0 years, 5 months, however many days.
2022-06-?? -> 1 year, however many months
2077-??-?? -> ~56 Years
????-??-?? -> Unknown
```

So basically, when there is a ??, that part is ignore and we only check the next higher part of the date, e.g. if the day is marked with ?? we only look at year and month etc.

Here is what I've thrown together so far:

```
@staticmethod
def calculate_time_left(release_date):
    # Only year is known:
    if re.match("([0-9]{4})-\?\?-\?\?", release_date):
        release_year = int(re.search("([0-9]{4})-\?\?-\?\?", release_date).group(1))
        current_year = int(datetime.datetime.now().year)
        if release_year == current_year:
            return "This year."
        else:
            return "~{} year(s).".format(release_year - current_year)
    elif re.match("([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-\?\?", release_date):
        release_year = int(re.search("([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-\?\?", release_date).group(1))
        current_year = int(datetime.datetime.now().year)
        release_month = int(re.search("([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-\?\?", release_date).group(2))
        current_month = int(datetime.datetime.now().month)
        if release_year == current_year:
            if release_month == current_month:
                return "This month"
            else:
                return "~{} months".format(release_month - current_month)
        else:
            return "{} year(s) and {} months.".format(release_year - current_year, release_month - current_month)
    elif re.match("([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})", release_date):
        release_year = int(re.search("([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})", release_date).group(1))
        current_year = int(datetime.datetime.now().year)
        release_month = int(re.search("([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})", release_date).group(2))
        current_month = int(datetime.datetime.now().month)
        release_day = int(re.search("([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})", release_date).group(3))
        current_day = int(datetime.datetime.now().day)
        if release_year == current_year:
            if release_month == current_month:
                if release_day == current_day:
                    return "Today."
                else:
                    return "{} days.".format(release_day - current_day)
            else:
                if release_day == current_day:
                    "~{} months.".format(release_month - current_month)
                else:
                    return "~{} months and {} days.".format(release_month - current_month, release_day - current_day)
        else:
            if release_month == current_month:
                if release_day == current_day:
                    return "{} year(s).".format(release_year - current_year)
            else:
                if release_day == current_day:
                    return "{} year(s) and {} months.".format(release_year - current_year, release_month - current_month)
                else:
                    return "{} year(s), {} months and {} days.".format(release_year - current_year, release_month - current_month, release_day - current_day)

    return "Release date unknown."
```

I am having a couple of problems here:

1. I am getting negative values for the differences of months and days. For example `2022-01-02` would return `1 year(s), -6 months and -2 days`.
2. I feel like I don't need to do all this regex matching for every case. There is probably a better way to do this.

How do I solve this properly? I feel like my approach is pretty poor and error prone.

Answer (score 0):

For the negative values, you can just use absolute value function to remove the negative. i am still looking at your code trying to figure out what you are trying to accomplish. Is this just for practice ? Also, since you are not using the script as an actual date for any real purpose, just treat the each part of the date (yyyy) (mm) (dd) , as a regular integer. No, I don't think you need regex just to figure this out but its good that you know a bit of regex. Treat the numbers as integers and just format them according to how you want to display the output. I am still learning python myself, just my two cents.

Comment: I plan on using this in a bigger project at some point, but I wanted to develop this algo isolated first, to make sure it works properly. I know one can calc difference with dates using pythons inbuilt functions, but since we are dealing with a specific format here, its a bit more tricky. Essentially I just want to figure out, given the format mentioned above, how many years, months or days the date is away for now. And the ouput should only show the parts that are known, e.g. if the date is YYYY-MM-??, only years and months till the date should be printed. Hope that made sense :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your overall algo should return, but here is a way to evaluate the parts of the dates:

```
for date_string in ['2021-12-02', '2022-06-??', '2077-??-??', '????-??-??']:
    year, month, day = date_string.split('-')

    year_delta = month_delta = day_delta = 'unknown'
    if year.count('?') == 0:  # if there are no ? in the year string
        year_delta = int(year) - datetime.now().year
    if month.count('?') == 0:
        month_delta = int(month) - datetime.now().month
    if day.count('?') == 0:
        day_delta = int(day) - datetime.now().day
```

Comment: I dont think this is quiet correct either. The return value of the algo isn't that important, I just want to calculate the remaining time until a given (partial) date. But for example `2022-01-02` yields a negative number for the months with your algo. And not only that, the amount of years is also incorrect. It returns 1 years, -6 months and -13 days. The answer should be 0 years, 5 months, 17 days (?) I think. I tried to roughly calculate it in my head, but you get the idea.

Comment: You're right, you can definitely get negative values.  If you compare e.g., August to February, so month 8 versus month 2, you can get -6 as the month delta.  So you would want to decrement the year delta, if that's what you are trying to do.  Similar issue with days versus months -- if negative, then decrement the month delta by 1, e.g., Aug 2 versus Feb 16 is not a full 6 months apart, so you could call it 5, and could calculate days in the month etc.

Comment: Do you mind editing this in your original post? Not entirely sure how you'd calculate the correct months if the delta depends on the days.